# Add the file content instead of the symbolic link to SVN repository

Tags: linux, svn, symlink

I created a SVN project on a Ubuntu PC and created on it a few symbolic links to files that are elsewhere, then commited it.

Then I tried to checkout on a Win10 PC, and when I opened a file it had a link text instead of the file content. I had searched about it and figured that symlink "works" on linux but not on Windows.

It happens that I wanna keep track of actual changes on the actual content of the file, not the path of the original one.

I tried to make a compare on Redmine, and saw that Subversion is indeed storing the symlink reference, not the file content.

Is it possible to fix it so that symlinks inside Subversion have their content commited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, symlink seems to not work.

My intent is to keep settings from various apps under SVN so I can keep track of changes I do, compare with old versions, revert, etc.

The solution I found is to use rsync. I created a script that syncs files and folders on both ways, then everytime I make a change I just run this script to sync and then I'm able to commit all files.